# dispatchKeyEvent from Service

Tags: android, service, view, keyevent

I have a floating view created in service, and I need to dispatch key events when I touch this view. 
I have found out that `view.dispatchKeyEvent(`)   needs context of foreground activity, and key event dispatching only works when activity is foreground. 
When you close/pause the activity and touch the view - nothing happens, even no NPE in `LogCat`.

Is there any way to use this method outside of main activity?

Comment: any luck with the matter?

Comment: I 've found an alternative way . I'm sorry I didn't post it , I'll edit the question or let you know on Saturday or  Sunday .

Comment: OK, thank you, you could inbox me at behnam(dot)heydarshahi(at_sgin)gmail(dot)com

Comment: I 'll post it ASAP , can't get home.

Comment: Please save me Nursultan, I am running out of time

Comment: I think others might be interested in what you've found. Please answer your own question.

Comment: Why you have create view in service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a bit too little too late but I found a solution. (Assuming the OP still wants to trigger OS back button from a floating view or service.)

It seems like it is possible to tell Android to press the back button, if you're a registered [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html). (Once your component is registered with Android, user must explicitly enable it in System Settings. So if this is simply a niche feature for your app rather than a critical function, it may be an overkill.)

Once you're done registering .etc. accordingly, your background service may tell the Accessibility Service to perform the back button, which can be done by calling

[`performGlobalAction(`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#performGlobalAction(int)) [`GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK) `)`

from the Accessibility Service.

*You do need **API Level 16** or above for this to work.*

<strike>I haven't got around to test this, but according to docs, this should work.</strike>
Tried and works on a number of recent devices. (Kitkat, Marshmellow and Nouget)

I found the app [Back Button (No root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.app58us.backkey&hl=en) on play store which seem to employ this technique to draw soft buttons for back, home .etc. (which works on LG Nexus 5X and Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2016)

HTH

Comment: Are there more types of key events that can be dispatched by the accessibility service? Can I make it type something too? Also, there is an app that somehow cause to paste text : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dhm47.nativeclipboard&hl=en  How does it do it? And how come it fails to do it on Android Q ? –

Comment: Accessibility Services can do most of the user actions on behalf of the user. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService 

Note that last few Android versions had a number of changes and play store changes the policies regarding this as well. But in general accessibility services can do almost anything including key presses, screen navigation, notification management and more.

Comment: I'm not sure about the app mentioned. Issues with Android Q may be due to a change in the OS or could simply be a bug as Q is still in beta.

Comment: Sorry my knowledge in this area is limited. My guess is `getRootInActiveWindow` can get you the root node which you can traverse to find the views you want and call functions on them such as `setText`. You can also call `dispatchGuesture` to send touch guestures to screen.  Note that you need to declare canRetrieveWindowContent on your accessibility service manifest. More information at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService
Also see the guides.

Comment: You can also call `getWindows` and interact with Windows that are not the active window if necessary. This is likely for Windows underneath the active window or when multiple apps are open in pip mode or split screen scenarios.

Comment: @Madushan wow, thank you. i was so young back then in 2014-16 ) i appreciate the answer though and hope it will be helpful to anyone seeing it

Answer (score 4):

If I right understand (you did not post any source you have), you need to have floating view over all over apps receives key events, outside your app.

There is some projects shows this ability. ([forum-thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531) [androidFloatingImage-repo](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/AndroidFloatingImage))

Try to use this floating views example to create each other, or use exactly the same. I think, using something i wrote above you can use callback on key event correctly. Hope it helps;

Comment: The most important problem is how to intercept key events when your activity is not foreground.

Comment: If you have facebook messenger on your android phone. It uses same floating views. It provide to enter text, on top of your screen over all other apps. I did not try this, but I sure it is possible to handle  key event. Did you try use i mentioned above?

Comment: problem is, I do not have EditText in my floating layout. So I need to intercept key events manually, but I don't know how.

Comment: What key event you need to handle? Did you mean KEY_BACK?

Comment: No, for example when user presses "B" or "C" key, on a keyboard connected to the Android device.

Comment: If you want to handle key like "B" "C" why it is not appropriate to use EditText for this?

Comment: The whole point is entering codes from hard keyboard and gamepads, not touch and EditText.

Comment: Looks like you all misunderstood the question. The point is that I wanted the view to ACT like back button. not intercept the key presses.

Comment: @NursultanTalapbekov Did you find any solutions to this issue? How can I pass the back press event to the activity under my floating view?

Comment: @Campiador Did you find any solutions to this issue? How can I pass the back press event to the activity under my floating view?

Comment: @unrealsoul007 nope, still waiting for Nursultan to share his solution. Come back and check again in 2016:))

Comment: @Behnam i know its too late but take a look at the accepted answer. Hope you've been doing well all these years and wish you the best :)

Comment: @NursultanTalapbekov this is great, thank you so much! wow were all so young! Hope you're doing great as well!